# How to find the total sum of the least selling product for a particular month (irrespective of the year)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that consists of products purchased by customers on a particular date. I first have to find the least selling product on the table for all the 12 months(irrespective of the year) and then find the total sales (sum of quantities) for that product for that particular month. I have done the first part that is finding the least selling product for the different 12 months. Now, how to find the total sum of quantities for that product occuring in the table for that particular month.

Query that finds the least popular product for all the 12 months

```sql
with
    min_quant_table as (
        select distinct month, min(quant) as quant
        from myTable
        group by month
    )
select
    distinct month,
    prod as least_popular_prod,
    quant as least_popular_total_q
from min_quant_table
natural join myTable
```

Output(just for ref):

```
Month        Least_Popular_Product          Least_Popular_Total_Sum_Quantity
1            Milk                           23126 
2            Eggs                           45514
3            Pepsi                          21457
```

This is the working example for the query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d756f/2

Comment: Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [this post](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and then edit your question as needed.

Comment: Thanks for adding the fiddle! You tagged your question postgresql but you provided a MySQL Fiddle. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Also, would you please show your expected output, given the data in your fiddle?

Comment: I am doing it in PostgreSQL. Sorry for that, but I just had to put out the general working of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I use T-SQL mostly, but I think PostgreSQL has window functions.  Your query looks good, I just added the ROW_NUMBER() function and ordered by the minimum quantity in a given month, then selected the top option for that.  In addition, I added the SUM() function for the quantities of each product in a month.

I think the following should be good, or at least point you in the correct direction.

```
;with min_quant_table as (
    select T.[prod]
    ,   T.[month]
    ,   MIN(T.quant) as min_quant
    ,   SUM(T.quant) as tot_quant
    ,   [rn] = row_number() over(partition by T.[month] order by min(T.quant))
    from #_tmp AS T
    group by T.prod, T.[month]
)
select abc.[month]
,   abc.[prod] as least_popular_prod
,   abc.min_quant as least_popular_min_q
,   abc.tot_quant as least_popular_total_q
from min_quant_table as abc
where abc.rn = '1'
```

Then your output will be something like this:

```
month   least_popular_prod  least_popular_min_q least_popular_total_q
1           Coke                    1557                    1557
2           Milk                    126                     126
3           Milk                    58                      58
4           Yogurt                  301                     1504
5           Milk                    1457                    1457
6           Yogurt                  363                     363
7           Yogurt                  17                      17
8           Milk                    1132                    1132
9           Bread                   42                      42
10          Yogurt                  730                     730
11          Milk                    210                     2632
12          Pepsi                   653                     7887
```